# Redirect to index.php of .htaccess dir

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

In .htaccess code is written as

```
RewriteEngine On
# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)?$ /project/index.php/$1 [L]
```

But this .htaccess is redirecting to index.php of my web root rather than that of the project. I have server which have wordpress installed directly at root (with its own .htaceess) and I have to get the `project` directory working with that . `.htaccess` of wordpress is written as below but I dont have access to edit it .

```
SetEnv PHP_VER 5_TEST
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !lp-variation-id

RewriteRule ^go/([^/]*)? /wp-content/plugins/landing-pages/modules/module.redirect-ab-testing.php?permalink_name=$1  [QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^landing-page=([^/]*)? /wp-content/plugins/landing-pages/modules/module.redirect-ab-testing.php?permalink_name=$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

How can I force to redirect to index of my project from my .htaccess

Comment: Well, if you cannot change that `.htaccess` style file, and it si in top level, then you cannot work around it, _except_ if you have access to the real server configuration. Coding such rules there is preferred anyways, since `.htaccess` style files are notoriously error prone, a pain to debug and really slow the server down. I'd say that requests to existing files won't get rewritten, for other requests there is nothing you can do...

Comment: What is the full URL you're entering browser and where is first .htaccess located?

Comment: `http://example.com/project/myfilename`

Answer (score 1):

Try this code in `/project/.htaccess`:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /project/

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Sorry **not working** has no information to tell me what URL did you try and what error you got.